# Use image with iText and AbstractPdfView

Tags: image, spring, itext, filenotfoundexception

I'm using iText for creating a PDF with the AbstractPdfView.
My image is located under

```
-webapp
--resources
---img
----logo.jpg
```

I'm trying to load this into my PDF but I always get a FileNotFoundException

```
Image.getInstance("/resources/img/logo.jpg")
```

How do I load an image which is located under my webapp folder into my PDF?

Comment: Your path starts with a /, so it's an absolute path. The resources folder is not a root folder, though.

Answer (score 0):

Was just doing that this AM...

ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
Resource res = new ServletContextResource(servletContext,"/images/logo.png");

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a folder inside src/main/resources. For example:

> src/main/resources/images

Inside this folder put your image. Let's say:

> src/main/resources/images/logo.png

Then you can use this resource from an AbstractPdfView as:

```
URL imageUrl = getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png");
Image logo = Image.getInstance(imageUrl);
```

Then use that image in your document however you need to.

Regards!